# Get Item ID from list when clicked android studio

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I am creating calendar app that shows list if the date got event from json web,
I want to show the detail of event in another activity when the event in list is clicked but every time I click the item, the TextView is showing the item position, not item ID

My OnItemClickListener Code

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*Uri test = Uri.parse("tel:3154431");
            Intent intentPhone = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, test);
            startActivity(intentPhone);*/
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailList.class);
            i.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

My Adapter Code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     Context exContext;
     int list_item;
     private final LayoutInflater inflater;
     ArrayList<ScheduleInfo> scheduleInfo;
     ProdiInfo prodiInfo;
     MarketingActionsInfo marketingActionsInfo;
     ProdiNameInfo prodiNameInfo;
     UniversityInfo universityInfo;

     public CustomAdapter(Context mContext) {
          this.exContext = mContext;
          inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     }
     public void  updateData(ArrayList<ScheduleInfo> scheduleInfo){
          this.scheduleInfo = scheduleInfo;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
          return scheduleInfo.size();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getItem(int position) {
          return scheduleInfo.get(position);
     }

     @Override
     public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          if (convertView == null) {
               TextView action, studyProgram, universityName, time;
               convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
               action = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.marketing_action);
               studyProgram = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studyprogram);
               universityName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.univname);
               time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

               int id = (scheduleInfo.get(position).getSchedId());
               action.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getMarketingActionsInfo().getName());
               studyProgram.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getProdiInfo().getProdiNameInfo().getProdiName());
               universityName.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getProdiInfo().getUniversityInfo().getUnivName());
               time.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getStartDate()+" - "+scheduleInfo.get(position).getEndDate());
          }
          return convertView;
     }
}
```

and here my DetailActivity code

```
public class DetailList extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_list);
          TextView idTest1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.schID);
          Intent in = getIntent();
          Bundle b = in.getExtras();
          if (b!=null){
              String j = (String) b.get("id").toString();
              idTest1.setText(j);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: implement `public long getItemId(int position)` correctly

Answer (score 1):

Whatever we are returning from the getItemId() of Adapter is what we are getting in onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id). 
In your case, you are passing the "position". So, you are getting the same in "id". So, please change it as per your need.

```
     @Override
     public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
     }

list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending long extra and trying to getting a bundle on other side. Modify your code like below:

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        /*Uri test = Uri.parse("tel:3154431");
        Intent intentPhone = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, test);
        startActivity(intentPhone);*/
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailList.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putLong("id",id);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put one TextView(say id of that TextView is tvMyId) in your custom listview row and set its visibility to gone. While populating data in adapter set id to that textview and retrieve id as follows

```
  @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              if (convertView == null) {
                //add this line
                 TextView tvMyId = convertTView.findViewById(R.id.tvMyId).

                   TextView action, studyProgram, universityName, time;
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                   action = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.marketing_action);
                   studyProgram = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studyprogram);
                   universityName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.univname);
                   time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

                //   int id = (scheduleInfo.get(position).getSchedId());
                   tvMyId.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getSchedId()); //and add this line
                   action.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getMarketingActionsInfo().getName());
                   studyProgram.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getProdiInfo().getProdiNameInfo().getProdiName());
                   universityName.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getProdiInfo().getUniversityInfo().getUnivName());
                   time.setText(scheduleInfo.get(position).getStartDate()+" - "+scheduleInfo.get(position).getEndDate());
              }
              return convertView;
         }
```

ItemClickListener

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMyId);
            String myId = tv.getString().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailList.class);
            i.putExtra("id", myId);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailList.class);
           bundle.putLong("id",id);
           i.putExtras(bundle);
           startActivity(i)
        }
    });
```

and in DetailList.class get the bundle value like this

```
   try {
       Intent in = getIntent();
       Bundle b = in.getExtras();
       long id= b.getLong("id");
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
   }
```